# How to prevent creation of additional Azure Active Directory tenants/directories?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security

How can I prevent users from creating additional Azure Active Directory tenants/directories? It is now possible as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant. We would like to lock-down this functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that you cannot prevent creation of other Azure AD. As it is totally free and open to create a new Azure AD.

Even a non work account would be able to create its own Azure AD from the following url: https://account.azure.com/organization

[image]

Comment: OK, I understand. But can we prevent changing directory for our company subscriptions with some kind of policy? If I am an owner of a subscription is there a way to stop me from changing the directory associated with the subscription?